# Error No puedes lanzar esta versión porque no permite que los usuarios actualicen a los APK añadidos recientemente

Tags: android, cordova, google-play-console

Cuando intento lanzar una actualización hecha en cordova, me aparece ese mensaje de error, he buscado en varios lados y en ninguno he encontrado la solución.

Este mensaje aparece al momento de revisar el apk para lanzar la actualización, ademas me aparece este otro relacionado:

> El APK no se puede actualizar Advertencia:
>
> Ninguno de los usuarios de este APK podrá usar los nuevos APK añadidos
>   a esta versión.
>
> Consejo:
>
> Comprueba que todos tus APK nuevos se hayan añadido a esta versión.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido para que sea mejor recibida por la comunidad tu pregunta **lee** **[ask]** y mira los consejos que se te dan ahí

Comment: Revisa [ask], te sugiero agregar una imagen de como se muestra en Google Play, eso será de ayuda a la comunidad.

Comment: ¿Estas reteniendo algun .apk? Que api soporta el que esta en producción y cual el que deseas subir  ?

Answer (score 5):

Debe agregar el código de versión de Android a un valor más alto, con esto el problema se solucionara.

Google respondio lo siguiente:

Hola,

Gracias por contactar con el soporte para desarrolladores de Google Play.

Estás viendo ese mensaje de error porque tu nuevo APK tiene un código de versión inferior al del APK anterior. Los APK más nuevos siempre deben tener un código de versión más alto que la versión anterior, o Play Store no sabrá que el nuevo APK es una actualización. Cambia el nuevo código de la versión de tu APK para que sea al menos 206020.

---

Espero que esto ayude a alguien con un problema similar.

Answer (score 3):

En mi caso, el problema fue que el número de versión del nuevo APK era menor al número de versión del APK que estaba publicado.